# Implementation AWS Xray with Typeorm Express

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, typeorm, aws-xray

I am implementing AWS XRay with Typeorm postgres having aws-sdk version 2.1044.0 and typeorm version 0.2.45.I am unable to trace postgres traces.
The code of my file in which i am trying to integrate AWSXray.capturePostgress()

> import { createConnection, Connection } from "typeorm";
> import { createClient, RedisClient } from "redis";
> import { appEnv } from "../helpers/EnvHelper";
>
> export interface KeyValuePair {
> [key: string]: T;
> }
>
> export default class DatabaseLoader {
> private static _connections: KeyValuePair<Connection | RedisClient> = {
> postgres: null,
> mongodb: null,
> redis: null,
> };
>
> private static _createRedisConnection(): RedisClient {
> return createClient({
> host: appEnv("DB_REDIS_HOST", ""),
> port: appEnv("DB_REDIS_PORT"),
> password: appEnv("DB_REDIS_PASS"),
> enable_offline_queue: false,
> });
> }
>
> public async Load(): Promise {
> console.log("Connection Loading...");
> for (let key in DatabaseLoader._connections) {
> if (key == "redis") {
> DatabaseLoader._connections[
> key
> DatabaseLoader._createRedisConnection();
> continue;
> }
> DatabaseLoader._connections[key] = await createConnection(key);
> }
> console.log("[\u2713] Connection Loaded!");
> }
>
> public static GetConnection(key: string): Connection | RedisClient {
> return DatabaseLoader._connections[key]
> DatabaseLoader._connections[key]
> null;
> }
> }

I tried several solution like add traces in driver key of create object. If any solution for postgres segment it will not work for failed query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to capture postgres queries using typeorm